# Issue uploading and processing xls in Heroku using Python Flask

Tags: python, excel, heroku, file-upload, flask

I'm trying to upload xls in my application and then processing it in backend i.e.**python flask**, the below code works in ubuntu 14.04 but **fails in Heroku** with Attribute Error **'Request' object has no attribute 'get_array'**

Code as below

```
import flask_excel as excel

try:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_obj = request.get_array(field_name='file')
```

Error in heroku is for the request.get_array
 `'Request' object has no attribute 'get_array`'

My requirements.txt in heroku has the below

```
Flask-Excel==0.0.7
pyexcel-xls==0.5.7
```

My HTML code is below

```
<form action="/upload_contacts" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="file">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Contacts</button>
</form>
```

I am referring this http://flask-excel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ link for uploading .xls/.xlsx file.
I did try searching for a fix, in github someone mentioned I have to use     **from flask.ext import excel** but this seems deprecated now and replaced by flask_excel.

Please suggest how to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: This code working on Ubuntu 14.04 but failed on Heroku,

Comment: I do not understand why this question was closed and directed to a question that is not helpful, get_array is specific to the Flask-excel package and is only available if you have installed it

Comment: !!  you can check the flask_excel ```flask_excel/__init__.py``` you will find init_excel function, to be able to use request.get_array  you must setup flask_excel first by calling this function, you imported flask_excel as excel so code should be: ```excel.init_excel(app)```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to use `request.args` [it return MultiDict](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict)

```
request.args[<paramname>] get first find param, 

request.args.getlist(<paramname>) get a list
```

[docs](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.args)

Comment: I need file parameter not list/dict parameter.